# Recyclerview with Swipe left/right row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have viewpager with tablayout, Inside ViewPager I'hv a Fragment which are creating a RecyclerView,

In RecyclerVIew roe item I have a created a Horizontal ScrollView, for getting swipe left/right motion,

Basically I want to swipe left the row only 75% of the screen and then show the swipeable view,

I was also used `ItemTouchHelper` of `RecyclerView`  but it swiping the complete row (100% swipe the row),

I know there are libraries available on google for creating swipe left and right gesture,

But all these not working properly because When we swipe on recyclerview item, sometimes touches goes to ViewPager therefore page get swiped I don't want that,

So that I using HorizontalScrollView, but the problem is that I can't detect swipe direction inside touch listner of HorizontalScrollView,

Actually we want to auto scroll after some amount if scroll on `HorizontalScrollView`,

Below is code which I have tried.

```
holder.scrollContainer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int scroll1st = 0;
                int scroll2nd = 0;

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    scroll1st = holder.scrollContainer.getScrollX();
                    Log.d("SCROLL", "Scroll down callded: amt is: " + holder.scrollContainer.getScrollX() );
                    mDataSet.get(position).isFirstSwipe = false;
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    scroll2nd = holder.scrollContainer.getScrollX();
                    Log.d("SCROLL", "Scroll up callded: amt is: " + holder.scrollContainer.getScrollX() );
                }

                Log.d("SCROLL", "max scroll amount: " + holder.scrollContainer.getMaxScrollAmount());

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    if(scroll2nd > scroll1st && (scroll2nd - scroll1st ) > 50 ){
                        holder.scrollContainer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                holder.scrollContainer.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                            }
                        }, 100L);
                        mDataSet.get(position).isFirstSwipe = true;
                    } else if (scroll1st > scroll2nd && (scroll1st - scroll2nd ) > 50){
                        holder.scrollContainer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                holder.scrollContainer.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_LEFT);
                            }
                        }, 100L);
                        mDataSet.get(position).isFirstSwipe = true;
                    }
    }
                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Basically ACTION.DOWN event is not called every time so can't not derived swipe direction

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `RecyclerView` is passing events to the scroll container.

add `onTouchListener` to `RecyclerView` and pass events to your `ScrollView`.

Comment: I am getting the all scroll event escape Action.DOWN, but sometimes Action.DOWN is also coming

Comment: Try with ACTION.SCROLL and see if you can catch it.

Comment: Basically I need X1 and X2 so I can decided the scroll directon

Comment: Try this library. Its very easy to implement and can be directly used with recycler view.   https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout